# angularJS - multiple filters inline using logical operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm curious if it's possible to have multiple filters on an `ng-repeat` inline using logical operators as opposed to writing a customfilter.
ie:

```
<tr class="first" ng-repeat="item in events  | filter : {date: showdate} || {isWeekend: 'yes'}"  ng-show="showAllEvents == 'true'"  data-date="{{item.date | convertDate}}"></tr>
```

So the expected result would display items equal to `showdate` or if `isWeekend == yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do or-filters inline, you'd have to write a custom filter function for that.

As for and-filters you can do it by chaining the filters, one after the other:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in events | filter: {date: showdate} | filter: {isWeekend: 'yes'}"></tr>
```

This would repeat for every item which has a date of showdate *and* is a weekend.

Note: This is also equivalent to the slightly shorter `filter: {date: showdate, isWeekend: 'yes'}`

Comment: Got it. Had a feeling. I tried doing this and saw it worked, but not with an or operator. Thanks.